# Hangfire: Is there a way to inject a hyperlink into the DisplayName Attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink, hangfire

Blake Connally made [a compelling case for Hangfire](https://youtu.be/LgjDPL5h-94).

I implemented his demo code, and wondered:

- Is it possible to inject a hyperlink into the `DisplayName` attribute?

---

```
namespace HangfireDemo.Core.Demo
{
    public interface IDemoService
    {
        void RunDemoTask(PerformContext context);
    }

    public class DemoService : IDemoService
    {
        [DisplayName("Data Gathering Task <a href=\"jira.contoso.com\">Confluence Page</a>")]
        public void RunDemoTask(PerformContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is a task that ran from the demo service.");
            BackgroundJob.ContinueJobWith(context.BackgroundJob.Id, () => NextJob());
        }

        public void NextJob()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is my next task.");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Example of a Link Inside of a Hangfire Dashboard]

Comment: Not sure about hangfire, but in C# this isnt possible. The attribute arguments must be constant. However, you could write your custom display name attribute that derives from DisplayName attribute, to have a property for the link and then set the DisplayName property on the base

Comment: @Jinish The attribute argument **can** remain constant, but the `a` tag must be rendered in the html as an `a` tag; not as an inline string.

Comment: Aah, right I got ya. Attributes are applied through reflecting over the property name or the value provided in the argument. For this to work the code that applies the attributes must know how to render Html tags and it doesnt as far as I am aware. I would be interested to know if you do end up finding something on this.

Comment: @Jinish: Correct. This is precisely my problem.